# How is it possible to customize a Menu to add customView or button or else

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I would like to know how it is possible to customize a NSMenu items and add custom view or any other control instead of menu items? is there a way?
please show me with codes if possible.

Comment: Found it :D such a silly question, but if anyone else as beginner as me find it useful, you just need to Right-Click on you menu item in .xib file and link item view to you your control (button,customView or any other control) and leave. Thats it.

Comment: Would you go ahead and post that as an answer, and accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it :D such a silly question, but if anyone else as beginner as me find it useful, you just need to Right-Click on you menu item in .xib file and link item view to you your control (button,customView or any other control) and leave. Thats it.